# HKHealthKit Watch OS - Calculate velocity or 'Pace'

Tags: ios, watch, healthkit

This is a general question seeking advice on the pattern required to calculate a user's velocity / pace / speed, when running or swimming.

Specifically, I want to be able to calculate this from watch OS, disconnected from the companion phone.

With GPS capabilities of Watch 3 / Watch OS 10.0 would the best approach be to:

1. Start Location Manager
2. Calculate distance and time between location points...
3. Calculate average speed?

Or are there better alternatives?

There is a good article here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/watchkit-2-hardware-bits-the-accelerometer/ that recommends using CoreMotion for device speed. However, this in my view would rather represent the 'device-speed' and not necessarily the user's speed over distance.

Any advice or experiences would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The article you linked to is for WatchOS 2, not Watch 2. The motion tracking is pretty good, but to get accurate device speed you will still need to use the GPS.

If you don't need to do any other location related calculations, and don't need real time data (**EDIT** you can get near real time data with an `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`. This is sufficient for most situations)  then you don't need to start location manager, just an HKWorkoutSession. This will default to using the GPS or Motion Data (which ever is more accurate/available at the time) and manage everything for you. When the workout is over, you can query for the distance samples and calculate pace from that.

If you need live motion data then the steps you outlined are correct, however you should check that the user is outdoors first. If the user is indoors or has a weak GPS signal switch to using Motion Data (and be sure to set the `HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout` appropriately if using HealthKit).